# Remove children of deleting the parent in many to one relation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Parent Class:

```
public class Article implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
Long id;

@Email
@NotNull
@Column(name = "email")
String email;

@Column(name = "title")
String title;

@Column(name = "published")
Boolean published;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "article", cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE},  orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<Comment> comments = new HashSet<>();

// setters and getters
}
```

Child Class:

```
public class Comment implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
Long id;

@Email
@NotNull
@Column(name = "email")
String email;

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "article_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
Article article;

// setters and getters
}
```

what i want to do is when deleting article for example with id = "1" it should delete all of its comments automatically ... so how to do that with annotations ??
**in other words**
for example when make delete request on postman on `http://localhost:8080/articles/1` where 1 is article id to delete ... it should delete all of its comments aswell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Add OneToMany relation from `Article` to the `Comment`:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "article", orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<Comment> comments = new HashSet<>();
```

Cascading REMOVE operations from the parent to the child require a relation from the parent to the child.

**Update:** Added `orphanRemoval = true`

Comment: i wrote these line in article.class and it doesnt delete the children

Comment: Try to add _orphanRemoval = true_, as in my updated answer

Comment: the rows of the comments table doesnt deleted

Answer (score 1):

You shoud create other side of relationship is `Article` which is:

`@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.All)
@JoinColumn(name="article_id")
List<Comment> comments`

So with this relationship if you delete one `Article` all its comments will delete.

Comment: Did you get an exception?

Comment: Can you please send new changes in your codes?
And the queries?! Delete codes also

Comment: Delete the `mappedBy` and use the second annotaion such as my answer.
With `mappedBy` the `Article` is not the owner of relationship.
Use `@JoinColunn` and `cascadeType.All`.

Comment: Yes even with your solution the comments rows stay the same without deleting

Comment: Use `fetch=FetchType.Eager` in `@OneToMany`.

Comment: still the same !!

Comment: I haven't any idea. Send your controller and dao if you have.